# Table calculations in Looker with a group by condition

Tags: postgresql, sum, amazon-redshift, window-functions, looker

My dataset looks like the following (first four columns) -

```
Person Rate Count  isImportant  Results
A       $2    15    true        $2
B       $1    30    true        $1
B       $3    10    false       (3*10+2.5*25)/(10+25)
B       $2.5  25    false       (3*10+2.5*25)/(10+25)
D       $1.5  20    false       $1.5
```

How can I generate the fifth column, `Results` by grouping the columns, `Person` and `isImportant` and calculating the weighted average of the `Rate` and `Count` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    sum(rate * count) over(partition by person, isImportant)
        / sum(count) over(partition by person, isImportant) result
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thanks GMB. This worked in SQL runner. How can we implement it in the explore using table calculations to calculate the 'Results' column?